# Unit testing for "FileNotFoundError" in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I have the following code and wanted to untitest when the given function raises for "FileNotFoundError

```
def get_token():
try:
    auth = get_auth() # This function returns auth ,if file exists else throws "FileNotFoundError
except FileNotFoundError: 
    auth= create_auth()
return auth
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to test the condition where it raises "FileNotFoundError" and doesn't call create_auth.

Any hint would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your unit test you'd need to mock the `get_auth` function and cause it to raise a `FileNotFoundError` by using the `.side_effect` attribute:

```
@mock.patch('path.to.my.file.get_auth')
def test_my_test(self, mock_get_auth):
    mock_get_auth.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
```

You can then test whether `create_auth` was actually called:

```
@mock.patch('path.to.my.file.create_auth')
@mock.patch('path.to.my.file.get_auth')
def test_my_test(self, mock_get_auth, mock_create_auth):
    mock_get_auth.side_effect = FileNotFoundError
    get_token()
    self.assertTrue(mock_create_auth.called)
```